# Upload file generated by javascript to server.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have some JavaScript code that dynamically generates a kml or xml file when the user clicks a button. I would like to be able to upload this file after it is generated to my Django server. There is no file input field where the user inputs a file from his/her computer. The file is simply generated dynamically based on other content.

Is there a way to simulate a file upload without actually having a form in your html, perhaps by generating the form with javascript/jquery and somehow injecting the the generated file in the form ?

Please advise how could this be done.

Here is my Django view for handling the upload which works fine with user input files:

```
def file_upload(request):
if request.is_ajax():   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileUploadForm(files=request.FILES)
        instance = Files(user=request.user, file=request.FILES['file'])
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list_files(request.user)))
else:
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list_files(request.user)))
```

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by "a file" - if the "file" is generated by javascript on the client (hence requiring a file upload control) then it will *not* be a file stored on the hard-drive (so won't need a file-upload control), but will just be some text in a variable which can place in a text or hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're having difficulty making a proper ajax request.

As @freedomn-m commented, the "file" you referred currently only exists only in memory.

So the best way to handle this is simply DON'T use `FileUploadForm` to receive data on server side, since you don't really have any file to upload. Just use something that handles plain string will suffice.

Let's say in your js code, you store your generated xml in `var xmlFile`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/your_url');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
xhr.send(xmlFile);
```

Now in django:

```
if request.is_ajax():   
if request.method == 'POST':
    file_content = request.body
    instance = Files(user=request.user, file=ContentFile(file_content))
    instance.save()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list_files(request.user)))
```

That's it.

Refs:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class